# Как удалить пользовательские типы записей при смене темы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как удалить пользовательские типы записей и таксономий из меню админ панели при смене темы wordpress? Тему сменил - делаю новую, а в админке пользовательские типы записей и таксономий из предыдущей темы остались. Хотя function.php заново пишу и там нет их регистраций. Как то можно их удалить не возвращаясь к старой теме?

Answer (score 0):

Плагин WordPress Reset. Все почистит. Я еще перед ним старую тему удалил через админку - файлы с темой удалились, а вот надстройки все равно оставались.